# How can I solve this using BIT?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I found a nice math problem, but I still can't solve it, I tried to find one solution using google and found that it can be solve using the Binary Indexed Tree data structure, but the solution is not clear to me.

Here the Problem called Finding Magic Triplets, it can be found in Uva online judge:

(a + b^2) mod k = c^3 mod k, where a<=b<=c and 1 <= a, b, c <= n.

given n and k (1 <= n, k <= 10^5), how many different magic triplets exist for known values of n and k. A triplet is different from another if any of the three values is not same in both triplets.

and here the solution that I found:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int64;

const int MAX_K = (int)(1e5);

int N, K;

struct BinaryIndexedTree{

    typedef int64 bit_t;

    static const int MAX_BIT = 3*MAX_K + 1;
    bit_t data[MAX_BIT+1];
    int SIZE;

    void init(int size){
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
        SIZE = size;
    }

    bit_t sum(int n){
        bit_t ret = 0;
        for(;n;n-=n&-n){
            ret += data[n];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    bit_t sum(int from, int to){
        return sum(to)-sum(from);
    }

    void add(int n, bit_t x){
        for(n++;n<=SIZE;n+=n&-n){
            data[n]+=x;
        }
    }
};

BinaryIndexedTree bitree;


void init(){
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &K);
}

int64 solve(){
    bitree.init(2*K+1);

    int64 ans = 0;
    for(int64 i=N; i>=1; i--){
        int64 b = i * i % K, c = i * i * i % K;
        bitree.add(c, 1);
        bitree.add(c+K, 1);
        bitree.add(c+2*K, 1);
        int64 len = i;
        if(len >= K){
            ans += (len / K) * bitree.sum(K);
            len %= K;
        }
        if(len > 0){
            ans += bitree.sum(b + 1, b + len + 1);
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int main(){
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        init();
        printf("Case %d: %lld\n", i+1, solve());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would be very appreciated for any reply, because I have days trying to solve this one.